# Horizontal scrolling slider / carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, horizontal-scrolling

Im working on a project page where i want a horizontal scrolling project/image slider.
No matter what im trying i can't seem to make it work.

This is the design, where the projects would need to slide based on mouse wheel scroll down. [Design of what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwJm5.jpg)

I work with tailwind and html / javascript.

If anyone knows a solution that would be very much appreciated.

[The homepage slider on this we bsite](https://tomekmichalski.com/) is a prime example of something im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo I created for you. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/q3r6kd0y/)

You can use slick.js to achieve your goal easily, the slick slider doesn't have a scroll wheel control function by default, but you can build one using the snippet below.

```
$("my_slider").on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sharing code snippet here. From what I understand all you are trying to achieve is a simple horizontal scroll

try this

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent img {
  margin-right: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" />
  <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/q:60/91/181391-050-1DA18304/cat-toes-paw-number-paws-tiger-tabby.jpg" alt="cat photo" height="300px" width="200px" /></div>
```

or you can use utilities in tailwind

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow#scroll-horizontally-always

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want if you are using Tailwind by giving the element you are working on a class of overflow-y-auto, like so:

```
<div class="overflow-y-auto"></div>
```